# Google Guava Cache - How to change refreshAfterWrite and expireAfterWrite at runtime once Cache is build using CacheBuilder

Tags: caching, guava

```
EventCacheLoader eventCacheLoader = new EventCacheLoader();

CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(200)
    .refreshAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(eventCacheLoader);
```

`EventCacheLoader` class has overridden load and reload methods.

But now my requirement is to change the `refreshAfterWrite` and `expireAfterWrite` value at runtime whenever required.

How do I achieve the same? Do I need to create the cache using `CacheBuilder` again? or any other way I can achieve the same?

Comment: These settings are static in Guava and you would have to recreate the cache. In its successor, Caffeine, you can use `Cache.policy()` to reconfigure it.